# Reverse Geocoding Mapbox results

Tags: flutter, mapbox, reverse-geocoding, mapbox-gl

When getting results from Mapbox API for the reverse geocoding results, I get only one specific result returned.  Is there a way to increase the results returned, say for a larger radius around the reverse geocoded point?  If a user clicks on a map, I'd like to give them options to choose from several places/addresses that are close to where they clicked, in case the spot they touched on the map isn't exactly correct.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to increase the results returned, say for a larger radius around the reverse geocoded point?

Yes. According to Mapbox's [Reverse Geocoding API](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/search/#reverse-geocoding), you can try changing the `limit`, `type` and `reverseMode` parameters. You can play around with that in the [API Playground](https://docs.mapbox.com/search-playground).

You can't directly control the radius, and the max `limit` is 5, but take a hard look at `type`: since you're concerned with "misclicks", but your application doesn't need the location down to address, but maybe just down to "neighborhood", or "postcode" level, if you set `type` appropriately you may not need to worry about the exact click location too much. So, basically, setting `type` as a higher-level locality type and increasing `limit`, you're effectively increasing the radius.

I don't think however Mapbox has an official Flutter SDK, so you might have to talk with the APIs yourself, though.

Comment: Yea, the issue I'm having is that you can only return a single item if you combine a type, say like an address or a place or POI.  I was able to make it work by creating two queries with a limit of 5 each, one for addresses and one for POIs.  It's a workaround, but I think it will do the trick.  Thanks for your answer!